# How to setup non-local bridged network for Xen?

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, virtualization, xen

I've had an absolute nightmare the past 5 days trying to set up the proper bridged networking for Xen. I've tried so many guides and all have failed to provide a solution for my specific question.

The IPs I need to configure:

- First Usable: `198.xx.xxx.74`
- Last Usable: `198.xx.xxx.78`
- 2nd First Usable: `198.xx.xxx.18`
- 2nd Last Usable: `198.xx.xxx.22`

I need 8 total usable ip's, 7 for individual dedicated ip's for servers and 1 to access the dom0.

My current interfaces file:

```
auto xenbr0
iface xenbr0 inet manual
bridge_ports eth0 
bridge_stp on
bridge_maxwait 0
bridge_fd 0

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 198.xx.xxx.74
netmask 255.255.255.248
gateway 198.xx.xxx.73

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 198.xx.xxx.75
netmask 255.255.255.248

auto eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet static
address 198.xx.xxx.76
netmask 255.255.255.248

auto eth0:3
iface eth0:3 inet static
address 198.xx.xxx.77
netmask 255.255.255.248

auto eth0:4
iface eth0:4 inet static
address 198.xx.xxx.78
netmask 255.255.255.248

auto eth1 
iface eth1 inet static
address 198.xx.xxx.18
netmask 255.255.255.248

auto eth1:1 
iface eth1:1 inet static
address 198.xx.xxx.19
netmask 255.255.255.248

auto eth1:2 
iface eth1:2 inet static
address 198.xx.xxx.20
netmask 255.255.255.248

auto eth1:3 
iface eth1:3 inet static
address 198.xx.xxx.21
netmask 255.255.255.248

auto eth1:4 
iface eth1:4 inet static
address 198.xx.xxx.22
netmask 255.255.255.248
```

Aside from the xenbr0 interface, the file was configured by host (secured servers, who refused to help with (understandable, it's unmanaged hosting...)).

The result of `brctl show`:

```
bridge name    bridge id            STP enabled     interfaces
xenbr0         8000.002590c30f2a    yes             eth0
                                                    vif5.0
```

Using `xm create /etc/xen/testvm.cfg`, I was able to start the domU but it's not accessible through the network.

The result of `xm list`:

```
Name                     ID    Mem  VCPUS      State      Time(s)
Domain-0                  0    2500     8      r-----        46.6
testvm                    5    4300     1      -b----         1.9
```

The `/etc/xen-tools/xen-tools.conf` config (summed):

```
gateway       = 198.xx.xxx.73
netmask       = 255.255.255.248
broadcast     = 192.168.0.255 (I wasn't sure what this was supposed to be)
dist          = lucid (10.04, I need to get the 12.04, but thats not important now)
```

The `/etc/xen/testvm.cfg` networking:

```
vif        = [ 'ip=198.xx.xxx.19, mac=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx'
```

I copied everything by hand, because I do not have SSH access since the networking is severely broken. I can only access the server though the unreliable iKVM viewer.

I would provide a ifconfig but I unfortunately cannot provide it, i'll provide anything else you guys need to help. I'd extremely appreciate a specific guide to fix this as it would definitely help others in the future, however linking to other guides which are similar to what I need is still appreciated.

Thanks for viewing, hopefully you can help with my nightmare :).

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you got your answer yet some where else,
also I am not by all means an expert in this (meaning Linux and networks)
but shouldn't your config. be the other way around.
you physical NICs manual and your bridged one configured as needed.
based on the config you show you only have 2 physical NICs

I am straggling with this myself right now, trying to setup XEN on ubuntu 12.04.
but every guide I see show the config this way, not the way you doing it.

hope someone one  with more Linux networking knowledge see this and confirm/correct me.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual


auto xenbr0
iface xenbr0 inet static
bridge_ports xenbr0 
bridge_stp on
bridge_maxwait 0
bridge_fd 0
address 198.xx.xxx.74
netmask 255.255.255.248
gateway 198.xx.xxx.73

auto xenbr0:1
iface xenbr0:1 inet static
bridge_ports xenbr0 
bridge_stp on
bridge_maxwait 0
bridge_fd 0
address 198.xx.xxx.75
netmask 255.255.255.248

auto xenbr0:2
iface xenbr0:2 inet static
bridge_ports xenbr0 
bridge_stp on
bridge_maxwait 0
bridge_fd 0
address 198.xx.xxx.76
netmask 255.255.255.248

auto xenbr0:3
iface xenbr0:3 inet static
bridge_ports xenbr0 
bridge_stp on
bridge_maxwait 0
bridge_fd 0
address 198.xx.xxx.77
netmask 255.255.255.248

auto xenbr0:4
iface xenbr0:4 inet static
bridge_ports eth0 
bridge_stp on
bridge_maxwait 0
bridge_fd 0
address 198.xx.xxx.78
netmask 255.255.255.248

auto xenbr1 
iface xenbr1 inet static
bridge_ports eth1
bridge_stp on
bridge_maxwait 0
bridge_fd 0
address 198.xx.xxx.18
netmask 255.255.255.248

auto xenbr1:1 
iface xenbr1:1 inet static
bridge_ports eth1
bridge_stp on
bridge_maxwait 0
bridge_fd 0
address 198.xx.xxx.18
netmask 255.255.255.248
address 198.xx.xxx.19
netmask 255.255.255.248

auto xenbr1:2 
iface xenbr1:2 inet static
bridge_ports eth1
bridge_stp on
bridge_maxwait 0
bridge_fd 0
address 198.xx.xxx.18
netmask 255.255.255.248
address 198.xx.xxx.20
netmask 255.255.255.248

auto xenbr1:3 
iface xenbr1:3 inet static
bridge_ports eth1
bridge_stp on
bridge_maxwait 0
bridge_fd 0
address 198.xx.xxx.18
netmask 255.255.255.248
address 198.xx.xxx.21
netmask 255.255.255.248

auto xenbr1:4 
iface xenbr1:4 inet static
bridge_ports eth1
bridge_stp on
bridge_maxwait 0
bridge_fd 0
address 198.xx.xxx.18
netmask 255.255.255.248
address 198.xx.xxx.22
netmask 255.255.255.248
```

Comment: I think this should principally work, but I believe there is an error in the setup. The lines 'bridge_ports xenbr0' should read 'bridge_ports eth0' or 'bridge_ports eth1' as desired.